# ingress external-ip doesn't exist

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, microservices, nginx-ingress

i made k8s service with
kubeadm, flannel, ingress-nginx(bare metal)
ON AWS ec2 instance (ubuntu 20.04). without EKS.

i want access my service with master node's public ip.

I tried with helm and kubectl to addon ingress-nginx

- `helm install nginx-ingress nginx-stable/nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true`
- `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.1.2/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml`

Then, applied an app, service, ingress

After that, `"kubectl get ingress" command doesn't show me ADDRESS and "kubectl get svc"` doesn't show EXTERNAL-IP

so, i patched external ip of master node with command

```
"kubectl patch svc nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":["<ec2-master-pub-ip>"]}}'"
```

I queried to that ip:port, but can't accessed.
also, i patched external ip with worker node's public ip.
when queried to worker node, i got 404 error from nginx

I want to know solution!!

thank you

add : ingress.yml

```js
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: node
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: node
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

Answer (score 2):

For bare-metal to use service type LoadBalancer you need to install a virtual Loadbalancer solution like [metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/)

Comment: but if you get 404 you can reach the nginx. Can you share your ingress resource?

Comment: i will add ingress.yml tail of my question!

Comment: add the ingressClassName: nginx below spec:

Comment: thanks! it worked for me!! but, it worked just inside worker node. If i want to query through master node, Do i have to use metalLb now?

Comment: it should work the some so there might be other issues like firewall or different services binding on tcp port 80 and 443. with MetallB you configure an IP Range. If a service Type Loadbalancer appears on the Cluster it gets assigned a virtual ip from that range. As you might not have a public IP range this might not be suitable for you though.